# What is Patterns that guide composition

Tags: architecture, software-design

In software architecture parlance, what is meant by "Patterns that guide composition"? Is it components?

Thanks

Comment: Post your question to programmers stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composition is when you combine two or more classes into a new one, in contrast to inheritance when you extend functionality for an existing class.

You should always favor [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) since it's easier to create small well defined objects (following the SOLID principles) with composition than when using inheritance (large inheritance hierarchies tend to move towards [GOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) classes thus violating at least Single Responsibility Principle).